# shipping Android app with a .realm file and use it as a default database

Tags: android, database, realm

i have a default.realm file in my "**assets/default.realm**" folder, I am not able to make it as a default realm database

```
realm.getDefaultInstance();
        src= new File("assets/default.realm");
        dst=new File("/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/files/");
        if (!(realm.isEmpty())) {
            Log.v("DB","already there!!");
        } else {
            try {
                copyFile(src,dst);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.v("DB","Wrong Path!");
            }
        }
void copyFile(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
        FileChannel inChannel = new FileInputStream(src).getChannel();
        FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(dst).getChannel();
        try {
            inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
        } finally {
            if (inChannel != null)
                inChannel.close();
            if (outChannel != null)
                outChannel.close();
        }
    }
```

but failed to copy please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of manually copy the Realm file, you can add it to your `RealmConfiguration`: https://realm.io/docs/java/1.1.1/api/io/realm/RealmConfiguration.Builder.html#assetFile-android.content.Context-java.lang.String-

Your Realm file might differ from your classes, and `MigrationIsNeeded` exception will be thrown. In that case, you will have to write a migration step: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations

So you will end up with something like:

```
RealmMigration migration = new RealmMigration() {
    @Override
    public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
        RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();
        if (oldVersion == 0) {
            schema.create("Person")
                .addField("name", String.class)
                .addField("age", int.class);
            oldVersion++;
        }
    }
};

RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.B‌​uilder(this)
  .name(Realm.DEFAULT_‌​REALM_NAME)
  .migration(migration)
  .assetFile(this,"Def‌​ault.realm")
  .schemaVersion(1)
  .build();
```

Comment: io.realm.exceptions.RealmIOException: Could not resolve the path to the Realm asset file.

Comment: Please post your `RealmConfiguration`.

Comment: RealmConfiguration config = new       RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
                .name(Realm.DEFAULT_REALM_NAME)
                .assetFile(this,"assets/Default.realm")
                .schemaVersion(1)
                .build();

        realm.getInstance(config);

Comment: `assetFile()` will look in te `assets` folder so you don't need that.

Comment: yes u were right thanks but now  io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: RealmMigration must be provided

Comment: Your Realm file differs from your classes: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations

Comment: actually we have to define schema of the database while migrating

Comment: RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
                .name(Realm.DEFAULT_REALM_NAME)
                .migration(new Word())
                .assetFile(this,"Default.realm")
                .schemaVersion(1)
                .build();

        realm.getInstance(config);