# Create Realm database on Windows

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, realm

Basically:

1. I have some data in Excel file (it's best way for my project).
2. I need to process it and write into Realms database.
3. Then place this filled database into android project as resource.

So i created simple console c# project to generate database. But then realized that i can't use Realms on Windows.

What is the most comfort way to do it if i work in Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin under Windows 7?

I think I can just send Excel file to my Android phone (or use emulator) and perform data processing and database building in Android application but... this just sounds wrong.

Comment: It is ok having your data on Excel right now. It's your choice anyway. Realm doesnt' work for Windows, so my suggestion is you can create the Realm File with an app built only for that purpose. If you copy the Realm file it is possible to include it in the app bundle. You can have a read on this previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38975192/shipping-android-app-with-a-realm-file-and-use-it-as-a-default-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have an internal build working on Windows but not yet ready for release.

So, yes, whilst it feels ugly, your Android emulator approach is the best idea right now.